# RestKit with CoreData and pagination

Tags: ios, rest, core-data, pagination, restkit

I have simple pagination scheme

http://api/users?page=1

gives users at page 1
after what i can ask next page like

http://api/users?page=2

and etc for next pages

But i have 2 problems:

1. i can't ordering users in response to show as them came from server to me

[user1, user2, user3] but when i try fetch from database i can got [user2, user1, user3] for example.

I try use RestKit metadata property

```
@metadata.mapping.collectionIndex
```

But it's work each request independently. Happen next 
for

http://api/users?page=1 i got array

```
[user1, user2, user3] collectionIndex will be [1,2,3].
```

But then i ask next page and got array

```
[user4, user5, user6] collectionIndex also will be [1,2,3]
```

so in database

```
[user1, user4, user2, user5, user3, user6]
```

it's not correct.

So first question: is it possible use collectionIndex for pagination requests without resets collectionIndex?

2. Problem in new arrived data

I ask

http://api/users?page=1 and got 2 users

```
[user1, user2] in response
```

after i ask second page and got 2 users

```
[user3, user4] in response
```

so i ask again page=1 and now i got users [user01, user02]

and then go increment page index but, in page=2 i got [user1, user2] and in tableview in UI i see al records

```
[user01, user02, user1, user2, user3, user4]
```

and then page ask nothing changes, so user can't understand is paging work?

To fix it i use FetchRequestBlock and then page=1 i erase all users - it's bad solution.

How to correct paginate data from server?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you need to add the page number into the store and add sort descriptors for page and index.
2. I'd say your solution is ok. I'm not sure I'd use a fetch request block, but you need to mark all the items as invalid or delete them when you start paging from the beginning.